# Android: verify legitimacy of a user server side

Tags: android, security, http, server-side

I have an app that retrieves data via http from a server. App sends a POST request with some variables to execute the query and retrieve the data in a JSON format.

The problem is I don't find a way to make the data secure into my server (only accessible to users that have MY application installed). If someone gets my app, and decompile it (even ProGuard won't avoid this for too long) a modded app could start sending requests to my server, using exactly the same protocols, parameters and IP address.

So, in a nutshell, the question is: Is there a way to check (server side, of course) if a request is coming from a legit user?, any way to check if the requester is using my app and not a modded one?

PS: I've been looking for questions like this one and only found another close one that suggested a "user login" approach as answer. I don't want to bother my users with any login mechanics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google offers a method to [verify back-end calls from an Android app](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) as part of Google Play Services which allows you to verify that the back-end call came from your signed application. One advantage that it has is there is no user login required to verify calls due to the client ID scope used to get the auth token.